# Bluetooth LE Scan Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I am making this app right now on android basically what it does, It scans the area for a Bluetooth device with a sequence of letter's that it starts with but the last four letters constantly change, also you cant connect to this device either. So I just do a scan and look for the device and if it finds it, it shows in my list and then I read the last four letters and convert them into a double. What I want to do is have Bluetooth start as soon as the app loads up and then keep scanning the hole time so I can get the last four numbers as they go up and they go down.

How can I do this?

Comment: Define "the hole time", what times exactly?

Comment: @TimCastelijns what I mean is either scan the whole time when the app is open or scan when it detects a change in the name

Comment: You cannot detect changes if you're not connected to the device

Comment: So how would I go about this situation then? @TimCastelijns

Comment: Just start scanning when the app launches, and stop scanning when the app closes? I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly? This is so basic, I don't understand what exactly you have trouble with doing

Comment: Yes it might be basic for you but there are people who are learning on here. I don't know how to scan and keep it going for the duration of the app while getting data from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done if you use advertisement data or scan response data. so your application has to run in central as well as in other peripheral devices. The peripheral devices has to advertise with advertisement data ( with a unique string and variable part). the advertisement data can be read by the central. 
Alternatively if you have the possibility to make the advertisement scannable, the advertisement data contains the fixed part (unique number/string) to identify the device and scan response data can be used to get the required number. note that the advertisement data and scan response data need to be set by custom application.